# Error: Cannot find module related to relative path from typescript to javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor, tsconfig

In our Automation test we are using Protractor with Typescript. So we want to avoid the relative path.
So in typescript we are using the baseURL and Path to resolve the relative path which is compiling fine.

```
  "compilerOptions": { 
    "target": "es5", 
    "module": "commonjs", 
    "moduleResolution": "node", 
    "sourceMap": true, 
    "declaration": false, 
    "removeComments": false, 
    "noImplicitAny": false, 
    "emitDecoratorMetadata":true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "outDir": "jsout", 
    "types": ["jasmine", "node"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
     "paths": {
        "factory/*":["factories/*"]        
    }

import{FactoryRegistry} from 'factory/FactoryRegistry.ts'


However, when we are running our spec file, the run time error is thrown 
 E/launcher - Error: Error: Cannot find module 'factory/FactoryRegistry.ts'
```

This is because the path which is resolved in TS Spec file is not resolved in JS Spec file. In JS spec file its says something like this

```
var FactoryRegistry_ts_1 = require("factory/FactoryRegistry.ts");
```

instead of `"./../../../factories/FactoryRegistry"`

So how can we resolve this when converting from TS to JS

Comment: I had the same issue with webpack aliases. I had to create helper function that fetches paths from tsconfig.json and transforms it to webpack-compatible format. There's an issue opened concerning this problem: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6710

Comment: Can you please share that helper function?

Comment: https://github.com/marzelin/convert-tsconfig-paths-to-webpack-aliases/blob/master/index.tsx

Comment: Is there any other way another than webpack... as  i don;t want to have any dependencies.
and if no then how this will be taken by JS. Do i need to write the code in package.json file for the same?

Comment: I think you can add this functionality by using the compiler API https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API.